# C Sudoku Solver Crash and Process returned -1073741819 (0xC000005)

Tags: c, pointers, crash, codeblocks, gnu

I'm currently working on a sudoku solver, and I'm mainly done, but as you can tell from the title, it crashes at start and gives me the message:

> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC000005)

I'm using Code Blocks with the GNU Compiler. I guess I've done something wrong with the pointers, I just don't know what I did wrong(currently learning C).
I really hope you can help me with my problem.

**My Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool finde_leeres_feld(int feld [9][9], int *reihe, int *spalte);

bool ist_legal(int feld [9][9], int reihe, int spalte, int zahl);

bool loese(int feld[9] [9])  //steuert den ablauf der einzelnen funktionen um das sudoku zu lösen
{
    int zahl, spalte, reihe;
    int *pspalte, *preihe;
    pspalte=&spalte;
    preihe=&reihe;

    if (!finde_leeres_feld(feld, preihe, pspalte)) // wenn wir kein leeres feld finden sind wir fertig
        return true;

    for (zahl = 1; zahl <= 9; zahl++)
    {
        if (!ist_legal(feld, reihe, spalte, zahl))
        {
            feld[reihe] [spalte] = zahl; // weist dem feld an der stelle reihe, spalte einen versuchwert zu

            if(feld[reihe] [spalte])
                return true;

            feld[reihe] [spalte] = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool finde_leeres_feld(int feld [9] [9], int *reihe, int *spalte) //funktion sucht ein leeres feld und gibt den wert true zurück wenn es eines findet
{

    for((*reihe) = 0; (*reihe) < 9; (*reihe++))
    {
        if(feld [(*reihe)] [(*spalte)] == 0)
             return true;
        return false;
    }
}

bool in_reihe_vorhanden(int feld [9] [9] , int reihe, int zahl) //überprüft ob in der gegebenen reihe eine Ziffer bereits vorkommt, falls ja gibt sie den wert true
{
    int spalte;
    for (spalte = 0; spalte < 9; spalte++)
        if (feld [reihe] [spalte] == zahl)
            return true;
    return false;
}

bool in_spalte_vorhanden(int feld [9] [9] , int spalte, int zahl) //überprüft ob in der gegebenen spalte eine Ziffer bereits vorkommt, falls ja gibt sie den wert true
{
    int reihe;
    for (reihe = 0; reihe < 9; reihe++)
        if(feld[reihe] [spalte] == zahl)
            return true;
    return false;
}

bool im_gitter_vorhanden(int feld [9] [9] , int reihenanfang, int spaltenanfang, int zahl) //überprüft ob in dem gegebenen 3x3 gitter eine Ziffer bereits vorkommt, falls ja gibt sie den wert true
{
    int spalte, reihe;
    for (spalte=0; spalte < 3; spalte++)
        for (reihe=0; reihe < 3; reihe ++)
           if (feld [reihenanfang+reihe] [spaltenanfang+spalte] == zahl)
              return true;
    return false;
}

bool ist_legal(int feld [9] [9], int reihe, int spalte, int zahl ) //überprüft ob es legal wäre in ein bestimmtes feld, welches sich in einem bestimmten gitter befindet, eine zahl einzusetzen
{
    return !in_reihe_vorhanden(feld, reihe, zahl) &&
           !in_spalte_vorhanden(feld, spalte, zahl) &&
           !im_gitter_vorhanden(feld, reihe-reihe%3, spalte-spalte%3, zahl);
}


void printFeld(int feld[9][9])
{
    int spalte, reihe;

    for ( reihe = 0; reihe < 9; reihe++)
    {
       for (spalte = 0; spalte < 9; spalte++)
             printf("%2d", feld[reihe][spalte]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int feld[9][9] = {{3, 0, 6, 5, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0},
                      {5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                      {0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1},
                      {0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0},
                      {9, 0, 0, 8, 6, 3, 0, 0, 5},
                      {0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0},
                      {1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0},
                      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4},
                      {0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0}};
    if (loese(feld) == true)
          printFeld(feld);
    else
         printf("Es gibt keine Lösung");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run your program with a debugger which will tell you where the program crashes.

Comment: Note: As you can see from `löse`, using english names in the program code is in general the better way. It also helps people on an international Q&A site like stack overflow understand your code better. Best is to write all code in English - including comments.

Comment: @Michael Walz Already did so, ith crashes at finde_leeres_feld (which i kind of guessed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool loese(int feld[9] [9])
{
        int zahl, spalte, reihe;
        int *pspalte, *preihe;
        pspalte=&spalte;
        preihe=&reihe;

    if (!finde_leeres_feld(feld, preihe, pspalte)) //<<<<<<<<<<
        return true;
```

You are passing a pointer to the uninizialized variable `spalte` to `finde_leeres_feld` which then is again derefereced in `finde_leeres_feld` which triggers undefined bahaviour here `feld [(*reihe)] [(*spalte)]` because `*spalte` contains garbage.

Your debugger tells you all this.

BTW (unrelated to your problem):

Why do you bother having the unneeded pointers `pspalte` and `preihe` ?

```
 int zahl, spalte, reihe;
        int *pspalte, *preihe;
        pspalte=&spalte;
        preihe=&reihe;

    if (!finde_leeres_feld(feld, preihe, pspalte))
```

instead of passing directly the pointes to `spalte` and `reihe` with the `&` operator:

```
 int zahl, spalte, reihe;

    if (!finde_leeres_feld(feld, &reihe, &spalte))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I initialized spalte and It didn't crash. And the debugger may tell me this, but I never worked with debuggers before(never learned how) so i didnt really understand what it said.

Comment: @Proximus well, it's time now to learn. It not that complicated and it's ahuge time saver.

Comment: I did so because i wasn't sur how it functions, I wanted to make sure I did it kind of right